# Can't convert varchar values to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple code. I need make easy operation: "column_A * 100 ", but I can't convert varchar type to int.
My error is: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.27' to data type int.

```
SELECT POWIERZCHNIA, 
POWIERZCHNIA * 100
FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow

--Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0,27' to data type int.

SELECT POWIERZCHNIA, 
CAST (REPLACE(POWIERZCHNIA, ',' , '.') AS int) 
FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow

--Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0.27' to data type int.
```

I want convert this values to int, but how?

---

@Larnu

```
SELECT POWIERZCHNIA FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,4),POWIERZCHNIA) IS NULL;
```

TOP 20 rows:

> NULL
>   1,08
>   0,21
>   0,85
>   1,38
>   0,00
>   2,88
>   3,00
>   2,40
>   1,00
>   1,36
>   0,30
>   2,16
>   3,24
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   NULL
>   2,88

Comment: have you got US settings in operation, as opposed to a country that uses the 5,62 format?

Comment: `REPLACE(POWIERZCHNIA, ',' , '.') * 100.00` should work!

Comment: @SphunaR, check ISNUMERIC function, added this to my answer

Comment: Also with ISNUMERIC i have the same problem - `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`

Comment: @SphunaR does `CAST(REPLACE(POWIERZCHNIA, ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(18, 2))` work?

Answer (score 4):

You can't convert a `varchar` representation of a decimal directly to an `int` (`SELECT CONVERT(int, '0.27');` will fail with the same error). You need to `CONVERT` to value first to a `decimal` and then an `int`. So, for your query:

```
SELECT POWIERZCHNIA,
       CONVERT(int,CONVERT(decimal(3,2),REPLACE(POWIERZCHNIA, ',', '.')))
FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow;
```

Note that I have used `decimal(3,2)` as we only have one sample value `'0.27'`. you will *likely* need to choose a different scale and precision.

This does, however, ask the question; why are you storing decimal values as a `varchar`?

Comment: He (most likely) does not want to convert to int and wants 0.27 * 100.

Comment: Possibly @SalmanA, however, we only have 1 sample value, with 1 error, and no expected results. This addresses both the why of the error, and how to address it in situ, but assuming that the value `'0.27'` should be represented as `27` could be wrong. Either way, however,  `SELECT '0.27' * 100` will error as well. You'll need to pass `100` as a decimal, or convert the `varchar` to one. For example `SELECT '0.27' * 100.0;`

Comment: Thank you, i'll be smarter :) decimal(3,2) or decimal(4,2) is okey. In my ERP system this column is "additional parameter" and must be varchar(40).. Your resolution doesn't work. Now is: "Error converting data type varchar to numeric." Also in: SELECT POWIERZCHNIA, CAST(POWIERZCHNIA AS decimal(4,2)) FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow;

Comment: Sounds like you have non-numerical data then @SphunaR. As I said in the above comment, we have but **one** example here to work with. Does `SELECT POWIERZCHNIA FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow WHERE TRY_CONVERT(decimal(10,4),POWIERZCHNIA) IS NULL;` return any rows? If so, post those rows **in your question**.

Comment: Also, sorry, when you post those rows, @SphunaR , please let us know the values you're expecting for them when they are converting to an `int`. Thanks.

Comment: With this select i have: 'decimal' is not a recognized built-in function name.
I tried `SELECT DISTINCT POWIERZCHNIA FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow WHERE TRY_PARSE(POWIERZCHNIA as decimal(10,4)) IS NULL` and I have only one - NULL

Comment: Seems you copied my code wrong @SphunaR, that `TRY_CONVERT` expression won't generate that error. At this point, I can't help you; there is far too little information.

Comment: @Larnu I have this error because Compatibility level for this database is 2008. 2012 is needed for this function ;) 

Maybe can you tell me how i can ignore non decimal values and take only correct?

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using 2008 compatibility,  @SphunaR?

Comment: Yes, main SQL Server in company is 2008 R2.

Comment: Time for an upgrade then, @SphunaR in all honestly. That version goes completely out of support in a couple of months. :)

Comment: I know, it'll be updated with new ERP ;)

I've checked on another server and your SELECT is working. I have 5427 rows and in this view is also 5427. So something is wrong., because it's all of them.

Comment: @Larnu I can convert to 'money' and it's almost good, because I have 108.00, not 1.08. 21.00, not 0.21 etc. And from money i can convert to int and will be 108, 21. So how can i change it to 1.08, 0.21?

Answer (score 0):

Do not understand why you want to replace , to . and then still cast as INT..., there is no point to do this.
Below should work fine, please test it.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('0.27' AS DECIMAL(5,2)) * 100 as int)

SELECT 
    POWIERZCHNIA, 
    CAST((CAST(POWIERZCHNIA AS DECIMAL(5,2)) * 100) as INT)
FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow
WHERE POWIERZCHNIA IS NOT NULL
```

**EDIT**

It is basically the same answer as @Larnu, just used CAST instead of CONVERT...

**EDIT**

You can use ISNUMERIC function to check POWIERZCHNIA

```
SELECT 
    POWIERZCHNIA, 
    CAST((CAST(POWIERZCHNIA AS DECIMAL(5,2)) * 100) as INT)
FROM v_analiza_cechy_produktow
WHERE IsNumeric(POWIERZCHNIA) = 1
```

Comment: The OP's value is `'0.27'` not `0.27` (it's a `varchar` not a `decimal`). Try `SELECT CAST(('0.27' * 100) AS INT)` and you'll get an error. Thus `cast((POWIERZCHNIA * 100) as INT)` won't avoid the error the OP is getting as the expression `POWIERZCHNIA * 100` causes the value `POWIERZCHNIA` to be implicitly cast to an `int` (as that is the data type of `100`).

Comment: Unfortunately: `Error converting data type varchar to numeric.`